# Error when importing contacts

Tags: contacts, import, error

I'm getting the following import error message when trying to import contacts:

Invalid value for field(s): Geo code 1

Can anyone please explain?

thanks

Comment: What fields are you importing?  Do you have the Lookup mapping info during import? box checked?

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of the data you are importing for that field. Geo code 1 is expecting a coordinate eg 25.0421407

Answer (score 2):

It seems to mean you are trying to import the latitude (or longitude, never remember) of your contact. Do you really have a column that contains that?

Sometimes, the suggestion to map your columns in the csv file and the fields in civi aren't correct, check that you aren't trying to import a completely unrelated "code" column into that "geo code +" field.

Your easiest bet to see what's the expected format of each of the fields is to export a few contacts from civi and include these fields, so you can see how you need to format them on your own file.